# Convert address into coordinates for Google Maps Local Context (Geocoding + Local Context Maps)

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I am attempting to plug Google Maps Local Context into my website, and I am looking to use an address string (1234 Main St, City, State, USA) to center and display a marker on my map.

Here's the code I have that displays a simple map on the site, but I need help getting an address to work instead of coordinates.

I have to use Geocoder, but I need help tying it together with the Google Maps Local Context map.

```
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction"],
    maxPlaceCount: 12,
  });
  const center = { lat: 37.4219998, lng: -122.0840572 };
  map = localContextMapView.map;
  new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map });
  map.setOptions({
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cegytdj6/

*code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction"],
    maxPlaceCount: 12,
  });
  const center = {
    lat: 37.4219998,
    lng: -122.0840572
  };
  map = localContextMapView.map;
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    map: map
  });
  map.setOptions({
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Local Context Basic</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=localContext&v=beta" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the simple [geocoder example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) for how to use the geocoder in the Google Maps Javascript API v3.
The code below will use the geocoder to return the coordinates for "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA".

```
let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({ address: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA" }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
      const center = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(center);
  new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map });
  map.setOptions({
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
  });
```

putting that into your existing code:

```
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction"],
    maxPlaceCount: 12,
  });
  map = localContextMapView.map;
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA"
  }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
      const center = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(center);
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
      });
      map.setOptions({
        center: center,
        zoom: 14,
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t4y53b2h/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction"],
    maxPlaceCount: 12,
  });
  map = localContextMapView.map;
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA"
  }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
      const center = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(center);
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
      });
      map.setOptions({
        center: center,
        zoom: 14,
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Local Context Basic</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=localContext&v=beta" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already have address and you just need to use geocoding API to convert the address into coordinates.
Inside of your script, you need to get geocoding API CDN with reloading the page. I will use axios to do that. Here is the code;
Add these two lines in the head of your HTML page.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
```

Now you can make AJAX request using axios.
Inside your script;

```
axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Your_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY`)
     .then(response => {
       var lt = response.geometry.location.lat;
       var ln = response.geometry.location.lng;
       map.setCenter({lat: lt, lng:ln});
       marker.setCenter({lat: lt, lng: ln});
      })
      .catch(error => {
      console.log(error) //or whatever you want
      })
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Irfan. I had trouble getting this to work, but another posted recommended another solution, which worked. Thanks again, my friend.

Comment: Thanks! But you can still use axios anywhere to make AJAX request whithout writing raw code.Leave an upvote if it helped.Thanks!

Comment: You absolutely don't need that. The geocoding is a service which is part of the JS API and therefore there is no need to call the web service (and to use additional libraries to do so...).