# Google Maps: getting directions after converting address to coordinates through geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I got the Google Maps to work with Local Context [thanks to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840839/convert-address-into-coordinates-for-google-maps-local-context-geocoding-loca) from [@eocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) but having trouble enabling directions from the nearby locations that popped up.

Here's the code I'm using. It seems like "directionsOptions: { origin: center }" runs too late, but I can't move it up since 'center' isn't defined until later. Is there any way to setCenter earlier? At least I think that's the issue.

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction",
"bar", "cafe", "book_store", "convenience_store", "hospital"],
    maxPlaceCount: 24,
  });
  
  map = localContextMapView.map;
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({ address: "25325 Main St, Newhall, CA, USA" }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
      const center = results[0].geometry.location;
      map.setCenter(center);
  new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map});
  map.setOptions({
    directionsOptions: { origin: center },
    center: center,
    zoom: 14,
  });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Local Context Basic</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=localContext&v=beta" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.maps.Map` doesn't have a `DirectionsOptions` property. Please refer to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions). You need to set it on `localContextMapView`:

```
localContextMapView.directionsOptions = {
  origin: center
};
```

That said, with the code you provided, if the geocoder fails, you will have no map showing at all. Is that the intended behavior?

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction",
      "bar", "cafe", "book_store", "convenience_store", "hospital"
    ],
    maxPlaceCount: 24,
  });

  map = localContextMapView.map;
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: "25325 Main St, Newhall, CA, USA"
  }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
    
      const center = results[0].geometry.location;
      
      map.setOptions({
        center: center,
        zoom: 14
      });
      
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
      });

      localContextMapView.directionsOptions = {
        origin: center
      };
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Local Context Basic</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=localContext&v=beta" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

If instead you set a default center and zoom, and adjust it when the geocoder is successful (along with setting new `locationRestriction` on the local context map), you would always have a map showing.

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  const localContextMapView = new google.maps.localContext.LocalContextMapView({
    element: document.getElementById("map"),
    placeTypePreferences: ["restaurant", "tourist_attraction",
      "bar", "cafe", "book_store", "convenience_store", "hospital"
    ],
    maxPlaceCount: 24,
  });

  map = localContextMapView.map;
  
  // Update localContext when user drags the map
  map.addListener('dragend', function() {
    localContextMapView.locationRestriction = map.getBounds();
  });
  
  // Set default center & zoom somewhere over NY
  map.setOptions({
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.61,-73.97),
    zoom: 10
  });
  
  let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: "25325 Main St, Newhall, CA, USA"
  }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === "OK") {
    
      const center = results[0].geometry.location;
      
      // Set new center and zoom
      map.setOptions({
        center: center,
        zoom: 14
      });
      
      // Set the location restriction to the new map bounds
      localContextMapView.locationRestriction = map.getBounds();
      
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: center,
        map: map
      });

      localContextMapView.directionsOptions = {
        origin: center
      };
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Local Context Basic</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=localContext&v=beta" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Super slick. Thanks for helping me better understand what's going on. Is it normal for the rendered Local Context map to not show additional POI results when the map is dragged or zoomed?

Comment: Yes, it is. You need to use `localContextMapView.locationRestriction = map.getBounds();` just like I did in the second snippet for when the geocoder is successful, but do that in a map event listener. See the edited second snippet where I implemented it in a `bounds_changed` event (that is whenever you pan or zoom the map).

Comment: Thanks. This opens up functionality quite a bit. Do you know if there's a way to change context for directions? (Walking vs driving)

Comment: Now, there's an interesting thing that's happening with this latest iteration, where every time I click on a POI that causes the bounds to change, it would close the placeDetails window and things could kind of flash for a bit. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/r6mb8f79/

Comment: No. Walking only apparently. Yeah, I didn't see this behavior. The `bounds_changed` means whenever the map bounds change... not only by user interaction. So your only option I'd say would be to use the `dragend` event which would adapt the locations when the user pans the map. That won't react to zoom changes though... and if you implement `zoom_changed` event then the same issue will happen. Remember local context map is still in beta. You should report issues and open feature requests here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853 Code updated.